# Ng-options not populating

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

So I have a `JSON` object returned from a `PHP` page. It contains accounts with their id, name, and number. I can repeat them all out onto the page, but when I use `ng-option`, it doesn't seem to work.

This works:

```
<p ng-repeat="account in accounts">
     ID: {{account.id}}<br>
     Name: {{account.name}}<br>
     Number: {{account.phone}}
</p>
```

But this does not:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="accountSelect" 
     ng-model="option.account" 
     ng-options="account.id as account.name for account in accounts">
</select>
```

This is where I set `option.account`:

```
$scope.option={
    account: $scope.accounts[0].id
};
```

Here is my Controller code, some things edited out to just focus on the problem area.

```
app.controller('CheckCallsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

getAccountTickets(1940713);

function getAccountTickets(callerID){

        $scope.searchTicket="";

        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "scripts/getTickets.php",
            data: {
                phone : callerID
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });

        request.success(function(data){

            $scope.accounts = data.Account.Account;

            $scope.option={
                account: $scope.accounts[0].id
            };

            console.log($scope.option.account);

            $scope.noTickets = false;
            $scope.ticketData = data;

            $scope.openTickets = $scope.ticketData.open;

            $scope.last30 = $scope.ticketData.last30;

            $scope.openAlerts = $scope.ticketData.openAlerts;

            $scope.last30Alerts = $scope.ticketData.last30Alerts;
        });

        request.error(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

    }

}]);
```

Could the problem exist, because I get the data from an `$http` request after the page has already loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/868/). See if you are missing closing bracket or something as part of controller script.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="accountSelect" 
         ng-model="option.account" 
         ng-options="account.id as account.name for account in accounts">
    </select>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.accounts = [ {id:1,name:'test1', phone:'1234567890'},
                    {id:2,name:'test2', phone:'1234567890'},
                    {id:3,name:'test3', phone:'1234567890'}
                  ];

$scope.option={
                  account: $scope.accounts[0].id
              }
});
```

Comment: Comparing my code to yours, I see no difference. I just get my `$scope.accounts` value from the data returned from a `$http request`. I can spit all the information out to the screen, such as all the accounts, as well as `$scope.option.account`, and it's all correct.

Comment: Can you please put your full controller code in question?

Comment: I added the relevant parts of my controller as per your request. I left some things out as they are either A) not needed or B) Working just find and are in a separate area of the controller

Comment: Please call function getAccountTickets(callerID) inside your controller  once you define it.

Comment: I don't have exact service to call but here is fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/LpbeLj99/7/ with similar concept.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it gets called earlier in the script. I just added a mock call. The function does fire in my actual script though.

Comment: Can you please use request.then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
  }); format

Comment: May I ask why? As that `$http` request works just fine and is returning the correct data.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create fiddle with same code. As most of the example i am playing with are using that format and here is the link to Angular JS documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#

Comment: The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Comment: So i don't know what I did, but it's working now. I appreciate your help. As you gave me the most help, I'll mark yours as correct.

Comment: Please make sure you update your latest changes in question so that it could help someone.

Comment: I have no idea what I did to make it work. Also, I'll be sure to update my `$http` calls

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are setting `$scope.option` when accounts are populated?

```js
angular.module('MyApp', []).
controller('MyController', ['$q','$scope',
  function($q,$scope) {
    var deferred = $q.defer()
    setTimeout(function(){
      deferred.resolve([{id:0,name:'zero',phone:'555-555-5555'},
                     {id:1,name:'one',phone:'555-555-5555'},
                     {id:2,name:'two',phone:'555-555-5555'},
                     {id:3,name:'three',phone:'555-555-5555'}]);
      },1000);
    
    deferred.promise.then(function(data){ 
      $scope.accounts = data;
      $scope.option = {
        account: $scope.accounts[0].id
      };
   });
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <p ng-repeat="account in accounts">
    ID: {{account.id}}
    <br>Name: {{account.name}}
    <br>Number: {{account.phone}}
  </p>
  <pre>{{option.account}}</pre>
  <select class="form-control input-sm" id="accountSelect" ng-model="option.account" ng-options="account.id as account.name for account in accounts">
  </select>


</div>
```

Comment: it gets it's value right after I set `$scope.accounts` value.  `$scope.accounts = data.Account.Account;
            
            $scope.option={
                account: $scope.accounts[0].id
            };
            `

This occurs when the Angular $http request comes back as being successful

Comment: Do you pre-maturely close the tag that has the controller? <div ng-controller><p ng-repeat></p></div><!--out of scope --><select ng-model></select>

Comment: Nope, the div encapsulates the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your case try to preppend your controller var name to your accounts var.

```
<select ... ng-options="ccount.id as account.name for account in CONTROLLER.accounts">
```